# angularjs http service wait for data

Tags: angularjs

I have HTTP service that returns promise to  `inspection2update.DamageTypeId` property and continue to execute further.

HTTP service:

```
function post(objectTypeId, damageDescription) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post(serviceAddress + "save/" + objectTypeId + "/" + damageDescription).then(function (response) {
        defer.resolve(response.data);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Here how I call service in controller:

```
inspection2update.DamageTypeId = damageTypesService.save(inspection2update.ObjectTypeId, self.dType);
```

But I need to wait until I get data from service and only after it, to execute further.

For this purpose I use `$q` service inside $http resolver, but still I get promise from my service and no data.

What do I have to change in my code to make service wait for data?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a promise which is resolved after the `http` call has finished fetching the data. The consumer who use this service needs to wait for the promise to resolve and `then` do something with the data.

Use the `then` syntax to receive the promise data and execute further:

```
damageTypesService.save(inspection2update.ObjectTypeId, self.dType).then(function(data) {
    inspection2update.DamageTypeId = data;
    // rest of execution...
});
```

P.S - as far as I can see there is no use of `$q` in your case (unless you want to mingle with the data / make logs, etc...). You can return the `$http` call as is:

```
function save(objectTypeId, damageDescription) {
    return $http.post(serviceAddress + "save/" + objectTypeId + "/" + damageDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the best of angular `promise` with `$q`

```
function save (objectTypeId, damageDescription) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
    url: serviceAddress + "save/" + objectTypeId + "/" ,
    method: 'POST',
    data: damageDescription
  })
    .success(function (data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
    .error(function (data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

And in your controller use `.then` function

```
 damageTypesService.save(inspection2update.ObjectTypeId, self.dType).then(function(response){ 
   /*use the response here 
     eg: inspection2update.DamageTypeId = response.id
   */ 
  })
```

Comment: What is the point of your deferred.resolved(data)? data will already be resolved when the call back fires.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you have your service method named `post` and your are calling a method called `save`. Is that an mistake? Second, I don't see any reason you should be using the `$http` service it is low level and your request is simple.  You should checkout [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) it provides a higher level of abstraction and will work for straightforward requests like yours.  Now, onto your problem. both `$http` and `$resource` always return a promise. so, typically in your service or controller you provide a callback that takes the response received from the request and processes it. Since the approach for $resource and `$http` are similar, but you asked about `$http` I will show you using `$http`.

```
   function post(objectTypeId, damageDescription) {
return $http.post(serviceAddress + "save/" + objectTypeId + "/" + damageDescription);
}
```

Now, in your controller you call the service method `post()` like this.

```
damageTypesService.post(inspection2update.ObjectTypeId, self.dType).then(mycallback);


function myCallback(response){
    inspection2update.DamageTypeId = response; // DamageTypeId now won't be populated until the request is resolved.
}
```

Comment: I try to use it in my example for get and it's dosent work

Comment: Please provide the code for your example with these changes.  And explain what "it doesn't work means". What errors are you receiving?